# If $M,A∈M_n$ and $M=AA^∗$, and all of the eigenvalues of $A$ have geometric multiplicity one ($A\ne I$).then, M has n distinct eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $M,A∈M_n$ and $M=AA^∗$, and all of the eigenvalues of  $A$ have geometric multiplicity one ($A,M\ne I$). Is it true that,

M has n distinct eigenvalues?

Comment: Counterexample
$$\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\1&0\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: After the edit: take a block diagonal matrix with one block the above matrix and another block a matrix $B$ such that $BB^*\neq I$. This is a counterexample.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut - Thanks, but why is this question  true?http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234910/a-question-on-geometric-multiplicity/234911#234911

Comment: The answer looks wrong, unless I missed something. I left a comment, wait and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample:
$$\left(\begin{matrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&2\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: I misunderstood the problem, thinking that $M$ had eigenvalues of geometric multiplicity one. As you point out, if it is this $A$ which has them, then we don't know about whether $M$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: @BenMcKay Ok, thank you to have clarified.